# How can i insert rows below in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to insert rows below user input, but my code is kept on adding it above.Can anyone tell me what is going on...

```
  Dim varUserInput As Variant
  varUserInput = InputBox("Enter Row Number where you want to add a row:", _
  "What Row?")
  If varUserInput = "" Then Exit Sub

  RowNum = varUserInput
  Rows(RowNum & ":" & RowNum).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Comment: `Rows(RowNum + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown`

Comment: @Comintern -- Can you please help me out with this..http://superuser.com/questions/1183851/how-can-i-add-listbox-after-inserting-new-row-in-vba

Answer (score 1):

Change `xlDown` to `xlUp`, like this:

```vb
Dim varUserInput As Variant
  varUserInput = InputBox("Enter Row Number where you want to add a row:", _
  "What Row?")
  If varUserInput = "" Then Exit Sub
  RowNum = varUserInput
  Rows(RowNum & ":" & RowNum).Insert Shift:=xlUp*
```