# How can I add Drop Down List after inserting new row in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to insert a drop down list with two items after adding a new row. This code below not working properly.

```
     Dim varUserInput As Variant
     varUserInput = InputBox("Enter Row Number where you want to add a row:", 
    "What Row?")
    If varUserInput = "" Then Exit Sub
    RowNum = varUserInput
    Rows(RowNum + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    With Sheet1.RowNum.listBox1
     .AddItem "Paris"
     .AddItem "New York"
    End With
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here.  Does `ListBox1` already exist or are you trying to add it?  Also, `RowNum` is a string - to get a `Range` reference you'd need `Sheet1.Rows(RowNum)`.

Comment: @Comintern -- I am trying to add Listbox automatically to new Row..

Comment: @Comintern   Dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro1()

RowNum = InputBox("Enter Row Number where you want to add a row:", "What Row?")
If RowNum = "" Then Exit Sub

Range("A1").Offset(RowNum, 0).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="London,Sydney"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

Note: I recorded most of this using the Record Macro tool on the Developer tab, then edited to use parts of your code. It's a useful method when you aren't sure the exact code required to insert something, such as this drop down validation list.

Edit:
To add two lists at the same time:

```
Sub Macro1()
'ask user for row to insert data
RowNum = InputBox("Enter Row Number where you want to add a row:", "What Row?")
If RowNum = "" Then Exit Sub

'insert dropdowns in column A
Range("A1").Offset(RowNum, 0).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="London,Sydney"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

'inset second drop down in column E
Range("E1").Offset(RowNum, 0).Select '<-- change reference to E
'Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove '<-- line removed as don't need to insert twice

With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="New York,Jakarta"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

End Sub
```

and with many identical lists:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim RowNum As Integer
Dim Lists As Integer

'ask user for row to insert data
RowNum = InputBox("Enter Row Number where you want to add a row:", "What Row?")

'insert row
Range("A1").Offset(RowNum, 0).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

'ask how many drop down lists to make
Lists = InputBox("Enter number of drop down lists to make in this row:", "Number?")

i = 0

Do While i < Lists And i < 1000
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="Hong Kong,Rome,Wellington,Cairo"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

    'move across one cell
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select

    i = i + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: This is not working, not able to insert entire row and not able to add 2 dropdown list using this method

Comment: sorry, I've never used a book. Just 15 years of trying things, and looking up code on the internet when I'm not sure. I'd recommend playing with the Record Macro function, and seeing what it produces - with and without Relative References turned on. And learn how loops work. Once you can make code with iteration, you can make useful macros that remove repetition.

Comment: It doesn't work when i try to add two drop down list.... am i doing anything wrong....I change little bit --Range("A1","E1").Offset(RowNum, 0).Select

Comment: The Range function takes only one cell reference as an input, you can't give it "A1" and "E1" at the same time. I'll show an example for two drop downs.

Comment: Adeladie--- wow you're the best.... what can i do or how can i improve myself to be a coder like you... please give me some tips or books. or do you have tutorial at youtube....